# What is query For check Constraint for upper() while creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, check-constraints

***In Below SQL Query constraint is not working its not checking the uppercase and send lowercase values to db
HELP me Out From This Situation***

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT_MASTER(
        client_no VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (client_no like 'c%'),
        name CHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK (name= UPPER(name)),
        address_1  VARCHAR(20), 
        address_2  VARCHAR(20),
        city VARCHAR(15),
        state VARCHAR(15),
        pin_code NUMERIC(6),
        remarks INT(10),
        bal_due NUMERIC(8,2)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `constraint`

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT_MASTER(
        client_no VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (client_no like 'c%'),
        name CHAR(20) NOT NULL 
              CONSTRAINT force_upcase CHECK(BINARY name = UPPER(name)) ,
        address_1  VARCHAR(20), 
        address_2  VARCHAR(20),
        city VARCHAR(15),
        state VARCHAR(15),
        pin_code NUMERIC(6),
        remarks INT(10),
        bal_due NUMERIC(8,2)
);
```

Of the next 2 lines, the second fails:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENT_MASTER(client_no,name) VALUES ('c123','ABC');
INSERT INTO CLIENT_MASTER(client_no,name) VALUES ('c456','alpha in lower');
```

`Check constraint 'force_upcase' is violated.`

[Try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=155d2e40342586fedc67bca759d2aed7) (MySQL 8)